# How Do You Tell A <Button> Where To Navigate To Using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a normal unsecure web page which has a `<button>` on it.  The problem I have is that this button should navigate the user the to sites homepage but I don't know how to tell it to.

This page is held in the sites CMS system so has no code to it:

```
<h1>Recover Password Complete</h1>
<p>A temporary password has been sent to your registered email account. Once you login you will be required to change your password.</p>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<p><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;</span>Return to the homepage</button></p>
```

The site is currently being upgraded to use bootstrap, MVC etc and previously the `<button>` was a normal `<input>` which i'm trying to avoid.

Is there anyway of telling the button where to navigate to when clicked otherwise i'm going to have to revert back to the `<input>`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onclick attribute like so on your button;

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='<your_url>'"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the btn class to an anchor too, this might be better than using javascript for navigation.

```
<h1>Recover Password Complete</h1>
<p>A temporary password has been sent to your registered email account. Once you login you will be required to change your password.</p>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="homepage.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;</span>Return to the homepage</a></p>
```

Comment: This is more appropriate solution.